# Need suggestion on Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I created few EC2 instances with instance profile attached. In the same config I created instance profile as well. But I feel reusability is lost in that case because while I am gonna create instance later for 2nd time using same config, it throws an "ResourceExist"error as instance profile is already created, so prepared below set of codes to sort this issue, but here I'm facing some conditional issues.

```
data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "profile" {
  name = "ec2_instance_profile"
}
```

#### In this section I want to implement a condition so that it will check first whether this instance profile already exists or not, if not, then go ahead to create with resource block. Otherwise it will fetch role_id/arn from data block. So need a help how can I create that condition

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "instance_profile" {
  name = "ec2_instance_profile"
  role = data.aws_iam_role.role.name
}
```

Please help how can this be created :)

Answer (score 2):

> check first whether this instance profile already exists or not

There is no such condition. In fact there is no functionality in TF to even check whether a resource exist or not. Also making your TF code dynamically dependent on existence of resource is [against TF design goals](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16380#issuecomment-517282340).

The proper way is to explicitly pass an input variables to TF, indicating whether a resource should be or shouldn't be created.

Comment: okay. let me reconstruct then. One more query, I worked in TFC enterprise, there I see if resources are already created, then it's skipped by terraform to maintain idempotency. it only tracks the changes, not all. But while I work on CLI, then noticed it tracks those resources which are already created and throws error.

Is my understanding correct. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AnirbanDas Sorry, I don't understand your new issue. Also since this is a new question, you new SO question should be made.

Comment: sorry. yep i created separate SO question